Issue with Hallucinated Outputs in RAG System Using LangChain and Chroma Vectorstore
I am working on a Retrieval-Augmented Generation (RAG) system where I input a simple PDF file and expect structured outputs such as the title, summary, publication year, and authors of the research paper. While testing the system, I encountered an issue:
First run: The output was correct and as expected.
Subsequent runs: The output started to hallucinate and deviate from the expected outputs. The structure remain same.
This is puzzling, and I am trying to understand why this might be happening and how to resolve it. Below are the details of my implementation:
Question:
Why might the system hallucinate on repeated runs, despite giving correct outputs initially?
How can I debug and fix this issue to ensure consistent and accurate outputs for every run?
Any insights into potential issues with the chunking, vectorstore handling, or RAG chain configuration would be greatly appreciated.
Code Context:

Chunking the PDF File
To preprocess the PDF, I used LangChain's PyPDFLoader and split the text into chunks for vectorization. Here's how I ensure that each chunk is uniquely identified to avoid duplication in the Chroma vector database:

import uuid

def create_vectorstore(chunks, embedding_function, vectorstore_path):
    # Generate unique IDs based on content
    ids = [str(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, doc.page_content)) for doc in chunks]

    # Filter out duplicate chunks
    unique_ids = set()
    unique_chunks = []
    for chunk, id in zip(chunks, ids):
        if id not in unique_ids:
            unique_ids.add(id)
            unique_chunks.append(chunk)

    # Create the Chroma vector database
    vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(
        documents=unique_chunks,
        ids=list(unique_ids),
        embedding=embedding_function,
        persist_directory=vectorstore_path
    )

    vectorstore.persist()
    return vectorstore


Structured Output Template for RAG Chain
The system expects structured outputs defined by the following Pydantic model:

from langchain_core.pydantic_v1 import BaseModel, Field

class AnswerWithSources(BaseModel):
    """An answer to the question, with sources and reasoning."""
    answer: str = Field(description="Answer to question")
    sources: str = Field(description="Full direct text chunk from the context used to answer the question")
    reasoning: str = Field(description="Explain the reasoning of the answer based on the sources")
    
class ExtractedInfo(BaseModel):
    """Extracted information about the research article"""
    paper_title: AnswerWithSources
    paper_summary: AnswerWithSources
    publication_year: AnswerWithSources
    paper_authors: AnswerWithSources

I invoke the RAG chain as follows:
rag_chain = (
    {"context": retriever | format_docs, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
    | prompt_template
    | llm.with_structured_output(ExtractedInfo, strict=True)
)

rag_chain.invoke("Give me the title, summary, publication date, authors of the research paper.")

